# Export React component to be used in a JSX tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The Goal:**

Replace the default burger icon of `react-burger-menu` with an icon from `react-icons-kit`. Example from the former's docs:

```
<Menu customBurgerIcon={ <img src="img/icon.svg" /> } />
```

However, I'd like to have a module of icons and import from that. So the above example would be something like `<Menu customBurgerIcon={MenuIcon} />`.

**The Problem:**

I get an error saying: *"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined."*

I'm exporting my icon like this:

```
// Icons.js

import React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'react-icons-kit';
import { menu } from 'react-icons-kit/icomoon/menu';


export const MenuIcon = () => <Icon icon={menu} />;
```

And using it like this:

```
// Menu.js

import React from 'react';
import { slide as BurgerMenu } from 'react-burger-menu';
import { MenuIcon } from './Icons';

// ...

class Menu extends React.Component {

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <BurgerMenu
        isOpen={open}
        onStateChange={state => this.handleStateChange(state)}
        customBurgerIcon={MenuIcon}
      >
    // ...
    );
  }
}
```

If I do the imports from `react-icons-kit` directly in `Menu.js` and write `customBurgerIcon={<Icon icon={menu} />}` it works. I suppose there must be something wrong with the way I'm trying to export the icon component.

How to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 return (
      <BurgerMenu
        isOpen={open}
        onStateChange={state => this.handleStateChange(state)}
        customBurgerIcon={<MenuIcon />}
      >
```

in Menu.js